# Inertiajs - use Link component to add record but unable to clear textarea without using a form

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have a simple textarea tag on a page with an inertia Link component styled as a button to add the contents of textarea to a database.

```
<script setup>

  import { ref } from "vue";
  let noteToAdd = ref('');

</script>

...

<template>

<textarea v-model="noteToAdd"></textarea>

<Link 
  :href  = "route('notes.store')"
  method  = "post"
  as      = "button"
  :data   = "{'note': noteToAdd, 'user_id': user.id }"
>

Add Note

</Link>

... 

</template>
```

The NoteController store method simply validates the textarea content, then runs a create method on it.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class NoteController extends Controller;

...

public function store()
    {
        $attributes = Request::validate([
            'note'      => ['required', 'min:3'],
            'user_id'   => 'required',
        ]);

        Note::create($attributes);
    }
```

All works as planned. The note contents are properly added to the database. However, I cannot figure out how to reset or clear the textarea on a successful add to the database without using a form.

This would seem to be simple, and I probably am just overthinking this, but everything I see documented requires a form, then clearing the contents (or individual fields) of a form. Setting the v-model property = '', doesn't seem to work either?

Can this be done without a form? If so, how, and would best practice be to handle this in the controller or in the link component, or elsewhere?

I can get this to work using a form, however, I'd like to do this without a form to possibly simplify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an example on `Vue SFC playground`. [You can see that here](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpVj81uwyAQhF9lxYXkUFu9tthq1XNvOXIhZFOjYkB47USy/O5Z/ySSJSS07Hwzwyi+UyqGHsWHUJ3NLhF0SH2qdXBtiplghIxXmOCaYwuSpVIHHWwMHQHhnUxG8xsv6KGalQd5alwHfBrMCDFAMn/oo7kU8vjkrEeTTxvM3OEIVQ2jDrC3LAbje2SB5NDpUwdVriW5Hg+EbfKGkCcA1bzXP7PvywJujho490SRQV4vstd2eGvnjEqLXaYWtSqfLytyztu9WMGX9c7+M7f7BnNLvCpXGSOzz9ZQTA9vrH9e).

This example doesn't use `Laravel Inertia`; however the concept should still apply. In your example, the `inertia/link` would use `@onClick` instead of `@click` if I recall correctly.

###### Using Inertia

If you can't utilize the `@onClick` or `@click` like the above example shows on `inertia/link`, then another option is adding a [router event](https://inertiajs.com/events):

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { router } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

const noteToAdd = ref('This is here on pageload.')
const clearTextarea = () => {
  noteToAdd .value = ''
};

router.on('success', clearTextarea)
```

```
<template>
  <textarea v-model="noteToAdd"></textarea>
  <Link 
    :href   = "route('notes.store')"
    method  = "post"
    as      = "button"
    :data   = "{'note': noteToAdd, 'user_id': user.id }"
  >
      Add Note
  </Link>
</template>
```

This code is untested.

However, my personal opinion is that best practice would be to just use the Inertia form. That would be best practice regardless if the code is bigger/smaller than without the form.

Thanks, hopefully this helps.